# Error Asynchronous Node.js call global sql connection exists / Can't set headers

Tags: node.js, sql-server, elasticsearch, async-await

I have a problem that somehow, my mssql Node-js api connection is not closed when I call the route...:

```
Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.
```

or

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

here is my MSSQL sql connection call:

```
var  executeQuery = async (query) => {   
    try {         
        var connection = await sql.connect(dbconfig);
        // query to the database
        const result = await sql.query(query);

        //console.log(result);

            //console.log("Result:" , result);
            sql.close();
            return result;  


        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
        } finally {
            sql.close();
        }                 
}
```

here the one for Elasticsearch:

```
const searchES =  async (req,res) => {
    const result = await elasticclient.search({
                        index: 'goldstandard-search-write',
                        type: 'joboffer',
                        q: 'namespace:pool'
                     });
}
```

I want to await for both results to come back to compare them with axios:

```
router.get("/api/compareCount", async function(req,res) {
    var query = `SELECT COUNT(*) as count
      FROM [DublettenReferenzmenge].[dbo].[DocumentForElasticsearch] where lastChange < dateadd(day,-1,getdate())`;
      var query2 = `SELECT COUNT(*) as count
      FROM [DublettenReferenzmenge].[dbo].[DocumentForElasticsearch] where lastChange < dateadd(hour,-8,getdate())`;
    axios.all([searchES(req,res), await executeQuery(query), await executeQuery(query2)])
    .then(axios.spread(function (esCount, mssqlCount1, mssqlCount2) {
        totalES = esCount.hits.total;
        totalMSSQL = mssqlCount1.recordset[0].count;
        totalMSSQL2 = mssqlCount2.recordset[0].count;
        console.log(" esCount: ", totalES, "\n", " mssqlCount: ", totalMSSQL,  " mssqlCount2: ", totalMSSQL2);
        //var result = esCount == mssqlCount;
        var msg = "ES Dokumente total: " + totalES + " MSSQL Dokumente total: " + totalMSSQL + "<br>";
        msg += "Critical: ";
        msg += totalES != totalMSSQL +"<br>";
        msg += "Warning: " + (totalES != totalMSSQL2);
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.send(msg);
    })).catch((err) => {
        res.send(err);
    });
})
```

In the above function,

```
axios.all([searchES(req,res), await executeQuery(query), await executeQuery(query2)])
```

I am calling twice the executeQuery function with 2 different sql queries. However, I am getting that error that my sql connection is not closed, or that my headers are not set, and I don't know why..:

EDIT: I think it could be some kind of race-condition... I am getting this error if I reload the route very quickly again and again.. It seems there is already a persisting sql connection open with that host, and it's actually not closing that connection fast enough to be closed when I again call the same route.. But otherwise, it works if I am reloading the page normally...

I think I have to built up the sql connection at the server.js level and return the connection somehow to have it available...or do this in a object-oriented way that makes me a connection object to manipulate and send queries with and only destroy it after I close the browser or so... but I have no idea how to do that?